Issues Implementing Overlap-Add Method in DSP for Audio Processing
How can i fix the weird sounds that are caused by my overlap-add code and get the overlap-add working correctly?
Example Audio of the weird Sound: https://voca.ro/11KK09nTgsXW
I'm relatively new to digital signal processing and have been experimenting with the overlap-add method to process audio signals. My goal is to use this technique to address discontinuities in audio signals that arise after certain operations, such as modulation/demodulation.
However, my implementation produces unexpected, distorted sounds, and the discontinuities remain unmitigated.
What I've Tried:

Initial Implementation: I integrated the overlap-add method based on my understanding from various resources. The approach was to apply it directly to the processed audio signal to smooth out discontinuities.

Adjustments: Realizing the initial attempt didn't yield the expected outcome, I experimented with the sequence of operations. Specifically:

Moving the Overlap-Add Step: Initially, I placed the overlap-add process immediately after the signal processing step. Observing the issues, I then moved it to post-demodulation, focusing on combining the real parts of the signals.

Varying Parameters: I've tinkered with different buffer sizes and overlap percentages, hoping to find a sweet spot that eliminates the artifacts.


The code:
#include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
#include <SoapySDR/Formats.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <stdio.h>   //printf
#include <stdlib.h>  //free
#include <string.h>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
#define BUFFER_SIZE 32768
#define SAMPLE_RATE 2.4e6
#define CENTER_FREQUENCY 100e6
#define TARGET_FREQUENCY 100.3e6
#define BANDWIDTH 200e3
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

complex float prev_sample = 0;  // Initialisieren mit 0 für den ersten Aufruf
complex float buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
complex float output_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
complex float output_buffer_prev[BUFFER_SIZE];
float demodulated_sample[BUFFER_SIZE];
float demodulated_sample_prev[BUFFER_SIZE];
size_t buffer_index = 0;

void add_complex_arr(complex float *arr1, complex float *arr2, size_t len) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr1[i] += arr2[i];
  }
}

void generate_hann_window(float *window, size_t length) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    window[i] = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2 * M_PI * i / (length - 1)));
  }
}


// Global variables for FFTW plans and arrays
fftw_complex *in_global, *out_global;
fftw_plan p_global, p_inv_global;

void initialize_fftw(size_t length) {
  // Allocate memory for FFTW input and output arrays
  in_global = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);
  out_global = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);

  // Create FFTW plans
  p_global = fftw_plan_dft_1d(length, in_global, out_global, FFTW_FORWARD,
                              FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  p_inv_global = fftw_plan_dft_1d(length, out_global, in_global, FFTW_BACKWARD,
                                  FFTW_ESTIMATE);
}

void cleanup_fftw() {
  // Cleanup
  fftw_destroy_plan(p_global);
  fftw_destroy_plan(p_inv_global);
  fftw_free(in_global);
  fftw_free(out_global);
}

// Big credits to HA7ILM for the FM Demodulation - This is very effecient and
// sounds great! https://github.com/ha7ilm/csdr
#define fmdemod_quadri_K 0.340447550238101026565118445432744920253753662109375
// this constant ensures proper scaling for qa_fmemod testcases for SNR
// calculation and more.
void fm_demodulate(complex float *in, float *out, size_t len,
                   complex float last_sample) {
  if (len == 10) return;

  float temp_dq[len];
  float temp_di[len];
  float temp[len];

  // Handle dq
  temp_dq[0] = cimagf(in[0]) - cimagf(last_sample);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    temp_dq[i] = cimagf(in[i]) - cimagf(in[i - 1]);
  }

  // Handle di
  temp_di[0] = crealf(in[0]) - crealf(last_sample);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    temp_di[i] = crealf(in[i]) - crealf(in[i - 1]);
  }

  // Output numerator
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    out[i] = crealf(in[i]) * temp_dq[i] - cimagf(in[i]) * temp_di[i];
  }

  // Output denominator
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    temp[i] = crealf(in[i]) * crealf(in[i]) + cimagf(in[i]) * cimagf(in[i]);
  }

  // Output division
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    out[i] = (temp[i]) ? fmdemod_quadri_K * out[i] / temp[i] : 0;
  }
}

int process_block(fftw_complex *fft_result, size_t length,
                  complex float *output, float target_frequency) {
  // Calculate indices for the target frequency band
  float bin_width = SAMPLE_RATE / length;
  size_t start_bin = (size_t)((target_frequency - CENTER_FREQUENCY -
                               BANDWIDTH / 2 + SAMPLE_RATE) /
                              bin_width) %
                     length;
  size_t end_bin = (size_t)((target_frequency - CENTER_FREQUENCY +
                             BANDWIDTH / 2 + SAMPLE_RATE) /
                            bin_width) %
                   length;

  // Allocate memory for the reduced FFT results containing only the relevant
  // bins
  size_t relevant_bins = end_bin - start_bin + 1;
  fftw_complex *relevant_fft =
      (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * relevant_bins);

  // Copy only the relevant FFT results
  for (size_t i = start_bin, j = 0; i <= end_bin; i++, j++) {
    relevant_fft[j][0] = fft_result[i][0];
    relevant_fft[j][1] = fft_result[i][1];
  }

  // Create a temporary plan for inverse FFT on the reduced set of bins
  fftw_plan p_relevant_inv = fftw_plan_dft_1d(
      relevant_bins, relevant_fft, relevant_fft, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(p_relevant_inv);  // Execute the inverse FFT

  // Normalize and copy the IFFT result to the output buffer
  for (size_t i = 0; i < relevant_bins; i++) {
    output[i] = relevant_fft[i][0] / relevant_bins +
                relevant_fft[i][1] * I / relevant_bins;
  }

  add_complex_arr((complex float *)output, output_buffer_prev,
                  relevant_bins / 2);

  size_t half_index = relevant_bins / 2;
  // Copy the second half of demodulated_sample to demodulated_sample_prev
  memcpy(output_buffer_prev, output + half_index, half_index * sizeof(float));

  // Cleanup
  fftw_destroy_plan(p_relevant_inv);
  fftw_free(relevant_fft);

  return relevant_bins;  // Return the number of samples in the output buffer
}

void execute_fft(complex float *input, size_t length, fftw_complex *output) {
  // Copy input data to FFTW input array
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    in_global[i][0] = crealf(input[i]);
    in_global[i][1] = cimagf(input[i]);
  }

  // Execute FFT
  fftw_execute(p_global);

  // Copy FFT result to output array
  memcpy(output, out_global, sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);
}

void fm_demodulate_real(const float *in, float *out, size_t len) {
  // Ensure there's at least two samples to process
  if (len < 2) return;

  // Iterate through each sample, except the last one
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i) {
    // Simple difference equation as an approximation
    // This is a basic form of differentiation; you may need to adjust scaling
    out[i] = in[i + 1] - in[i];
  }

  // Handle the last sample manually or replicate the previous difference
  out[len - 1] = out[len - 2];
}

// Main processing loop
void process_data(complex float *data, size_t total_size, SNDFILE *file) {
  complex float windowed_data[total_size];
  complex float output_data[total_size];
  fftw_complex *fft_result =
      (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * BUFFER_SIZE);

  float hann_window[total_size];
  generate_hann_window(hann_window, total_size);
  // Apply the Hann window to the output_buffer
  for (size_t i = 0; i < total_size; i++) {
    data[i] *= hann_window[i];
  }

  execute_fft(data, total_size, fft_result);
  int received_data =
      process_block(fft_result, total_size, output_buffer, TARGET_FREQUENCY);

  // Calculate the start index for the second half of the demodulated_sample

  fm_demodulate(output_buffer, demodulated_sample, received_data, prev_sample);

  prev_sample = output_buffer[received_data / 2 - 1];

  sf_writef_float(file, demodulated_sample, received_data);
}

int main(void) {
  size_t length;

  // enumerate devices
  SoapySDRKwargs *results = SoapySDRDevice_enumerate(NULL, &length);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("Found device #%d: ", (int)i);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < results[i].size; j++) {
      printf("%s=%s, ", results[i].keys[j], results[i].vals[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  SoapySDRKwargsList_clear(results, length);

  // create device instance
  SoapySDRKwargs args = {};
  SoapySDRKwargs_set(&args, "driver", "rtlsdr");

  SoapySDRDevice *sdr = SoapySDRDevice_make(&args);
  SoapySDRKwargs_clear(&args);

  if (sdr == NULL) {
    printf("SoapySDRDevice_make fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // apply settings
  if (SoapySDRDevice_setSampleRate(sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, 2.4e6) != 0) {
    printf("setSampleRate fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
  }
  if (SoapySDRDevice_setFrequency(sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, 100e6, NULL) != 0) {
    printf("setFrequency fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
  }

  // setup a stream (complex floats)
  SoapySDRStream *rxStream = SoapySDRDevice_setupStream(
      sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, SOAPY_SDR_CF32, NULL, 0, NULL);
  if (rxStream == NULL) {
    printf("setupStream fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
    SoapySDRDevice_unmake(sdr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  SoapySDRDevice_activateStream(sdr, rxStream, 0, 0, 0);  // start streaming

  // create a re-usable buffer for rx samples
  complex float buff[32768];

  SF_INFO info;
  info.samplerate = 200e3;
  info.channels = 1;
  info.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
  SNDFILE *file = sf_open("output.wav", SFM_WRITE, &info);

  initialize_fftw(BUFFER_SIZE);

  // receive some samples
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    void *buffs[] = {buff};  // array of buffers
    int flags;               // flags set by receive operation
    long long timeNs;        // timestamp for receive buffer
    int ret = SoapySDRDevice_readStream(sdr, rxStream, buffs, 32768, &flags,
                                        &timeNs, 1000000);

    // Check for errors in readStream
    if (ret < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error reading stream: %s\n", SoapySDR_errToStr(ret));
      continue;  // Skip to next iteration on error
    }
    // Copy received samples from buff to buffer
    // memcpy(buffer + buffer_index, buff, ret * sizeof(complex float));
    // buffer_index += ret;
    // if (buffer_index >= BUFFER_SIZE) {

    process_data(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, file);

    // buffer_index = 0;
    //}
  }

  sf_close(file);

  // shutdown the stream
  SoapySDRDevice_deactivateStream(sdr, rxStream, 0, 0);  // stop streaming
  SoapySDRDevice_closeStream(sdr, rxStream);

  // cleanup device handle
  SoapySDRDevice_unmake(sdr);

  printf("Done\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Your question doesn't have a question, so it cannot be answered. Please [edit] your post and add a concrete question that can be answered.

Sorry, added it with an example audio.

that is 323 lines of code. please consider pruning that towards a [mre]

@ChristophRackwitz yes, but most of the code is needed to replicate it. I can try to reduce it a bit but if it should be reproducable i cant take much of it away

wild guess: integer overflow/unterflow/wraparound. it's a bit too regular tho. buffer overflows perhaps. or you're integrating something that you shouldn't, ... -- that vocaroo sounds like noise, then some square wave, then noise. I'm not sure feeding noise into it is a good demonstration. also, vocaroo resamples and compresses the audio. you'd want people to see the waveform, undisturbed. dial down all the constants for time windows. make this run on 100 samples. plot them. [mre] means figuring out how to simplify beyond your goal, because debugging this is your goal now.

and you could test every function you have in there. write tests, or don't. but test these functions. use synthetic data for which you know what's supposed to be the resultt. understand and be able to explain every single bit of difference. to yourself. not to us. none of us will have the patience to dig into all that code. that's a lot of time for no gain.

I understand that, yea vocaroo compresses it. It also happens on am etc i think it could be overflow underflow or wraparound, maybe ill try to do the same in python.
